# How am I supposed to put out fires?

Tags: dark-souls-3

Okay, so I finally made it to the Crucifixion Swamp and I found a writing that said if I put out three fires then I'll be able to reach Wolf Blood. How am I supposed to do that? I tried using slugs, I tried interacting, I tried breaking them. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: “I tried using slugs, I tried interacting, I tried breaking them” — I presume fire works differently in this game than it does in real life.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite maybe you haven't been using enough slugs?

Answer (score 28):

You are probably trying to put out the wrong fires. Quest fires are interactable objects looking like bowls with flames. When you are close, the prompt "Extinguish flame" is shown:

[image]

Comment: Ohh I see. I was trying to put out campfires. I should've known that would've been too easy. But how do I know where those fires are? Do I just wander around until I find one or is there something I should be looking for?

Comment: @KerikoKraft other answer suggests they are at the bottom of towers, I don't remember if there are any other buildings in the area. Just explore it!

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers using the checkmark near the vote buttons

Comment: These fires are fairly easy to find, as they are all at the tops of the largest "hill" sections of the swamp. If you see a path leading up a hill; you've found one.

Answer (score 7):

There are exactly 3 fires that can be put out by you. Each of them are located at the bottom of each tower in that area. They do look like forge fires to me.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oj_ZNYydEOg) shows where the flames are located, but they are already extinguished.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer. I must've thought it was part of Arghtype's answer. My bad. Sorry again. And thank you!